# When using su to switch to a non root user, su fails to launch the user's shell program despite seemingly good permissions on everything

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, shell

**The error always looks something like this, depending on which shell is configured in `/etc/passwd`.**

```bsh
su: failed to execute /usr/sbin/jk_chrootsh: Permission denied
```

*OR*

```bsh
su: failed to execute /bin/bash: Permission denied # for a more typical shell
```

Upon examining both the permissions and file access control lists for `/bin/bash`, located in `/usr/bin/bash`, they seem to allow the user `backups` to read and execute both shells.

```bsh
┌─[✓]─[\u@\h]─[~]
└──$ stat --format %a /usr/sbin/jk_chrootsh # Get chmod code
777

┌─[✓]─[\u@\h]─[~]
└──$ stat --format %a /usr/bin/bash
755

┌─[✓]─[\u@\h]─[~]
└──$ getfacl /usr/sbin/jk_chrootsh
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: usr/sbin/jk_chrootsh
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::rwx

┌─[✓]─[\u@\h]─[~]
└──$ getfacl /usr/bin/bash
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: usr/bin/bash
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:backups:rwx  #effective:r-x
group::r-x
mask::r-x
other::r-x
```

The chmod code of **777** for `/bin/bash` will clearly allow rwx access to anyone, and the file access control list shows even a specific override for my user to have rwx access.

The chmod code of **755** should also give enough access for `jk_chrootsh`, with rx access being granted to everyone. Additionally, the `facl` shows nothing that would restrict the execution ability of *anyone* to /usr/sbin/jk_chrootsh.

I was concerned that maybe the `sbin` directory, usually being only for use with the root user, would be blocking read access, but it also allows read and execute access to anyone. I guess it just is not on the default PATH variable for non-root users.

This is the `backups` user's line in /etc/passwd if needed, too:

`backups:x:1002:1002:,,,:/opt/backups/./.:/usr/sbin/jk_chrootsh`

Does anyone have any possible leads for solving this problem?

**Edit:**

As per `harrymc`'s request, `/opt/backups/` has the permission code `777`, yet is owned by `root:root`, as sshd requires root to own chroot directories.

Comment: What exactly is your `su` command? To use the new user profile and variables do `su - username`.

Comment: My su command was just `sudo su backups`. I just tried with `sudo su - backups` and I received the same error, in addition to this one: 

`su: warning: cannot change directory to /opt/backups/./.: Permission denied`.

/opt/backups is the home directory by the way. I have that directory purposefully owned by root because I meant to set up backups with an sshd chrootdirectory of /opt/backups.

Comment: Try without the `sudo`.

Comment: Without the sudo, I get `su: Authentication failure`. I definitely typed the password correctly. I also `sudo passwd`'d the password to just `a` and I still received "Auth failure"

Comment: I think the permissions on `/opt/backups` should be added to your post.

Comment: I will add them to the post right now.

Comment: Just a word of warning: You should never su in to a lesser account. The su command does not protect against a program running in the lesser account from injecting shell commands in to the root terminal that su was launched from. Use something like ssh or telnet to localhost instead.

Comment: Thank you Alex. That makes a lot of sense. My end goal is indeed to be using ssh and rsync from a remote machine via the user `backups`, which will have a chroot jail set up to only allow it access to inside that folder (as well as the rsync program, /dev/null, and other pretty necessary things.)

Comment: Perhaps su has some protection in it preventing it from launching a shell that is writable by other than root? I see you gave /usr/bin/jk_rootsh 777 permissions.

Comment: Oh. I can give it 755 if you'd like?

Comment: It does not help. I still receive the `su: Authentication failure` with `su - backups` and `su: failed to execute /usr/sbin/jk_chrootsh: Permission denied` when I run `sudo su backups`

Comment: @Mini can you get to a root shell, such as with sudo /bin/bash or su - and then try running su directly from the root shell? Also consider moving the jk_ shell out of sbin and in to bin and updating with chsh accordingly.

Comment: This is what happens, same error:

`su: failed to execute /usr/sbin/jk_chrootsh: Permission denied`

I opened a root shell with `sudo su`. If you want, I can ssh in directly to root and try, but I will have to reconfigure my /etc/ssh/sshd_config.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135255/discussion-between-mini-and-alex-cannon).